# Qsort function to sort words in array uniquely

Tags: c, c-strings, string-comparison, function-definition, qsort

Im trying to build a qsort function that will sort words in my array of pointers **allwords, uniquely. But im going wrong somewhere, what am i doing wrong? (very new to C)

```
static int intcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
     const int *left = a;
     const int *right = b;
     return *left - *right;
}
```

Comment: If it really is an "array if pointers", your indirection-level is shallow by one. Of course, we're taking it on faith that you said what you meant. We don't know for certainly unless you post a proper [mcve] that builds your to-be-sorted data and presents it, and this function, to qsort. Unrelated, if it were an `int` array, not `int*` array, this function could "work", but possibly underflow, and will sort descending, not ascending, which again, we don't know is intended. I harbor grave doubts you're anywhere close, as you state you want to "sort words" .

Comment: So you mean "words" in the sense of *machine* words?  Which you are assuming correspond to type `int`?  You would need something quite different if you meant "words" in the sense of units of human language.

Comment: Also, what does uniqueness have to do with it?  And if you indeed have an array of pointers, then are you trying to sort by the pointers themselves or by the values to which they point?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Typically, a unique sort implies discarding duplicate entries.  That's tricky (if not impossible) to do using `qsort` and an ordinary comparison function, as it's not something that `qsort` is set up to do.

Comment: Note that even if `int` objects are being sorted, `return *left - *right;` is incorrect as it may overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If the pointers point to strings and you need to compare strings then the comparison function will look like

```
static int intcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
     const char *left = *( const char ** )a;
     const char *right = *( const char ** )b;
     return strcmp( left, right );
}
```

Pay attention to that `qsort` passes to the comparison function pointers to elements of the sorted array. As elements in your case have the type `char *` then pointers to them will have the type `char **` that are assigned to pointers of the type `const void *`. So within the comparison function you need to do a "reverse" casting  of pointers from `const void *` to `const char **`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int cmp( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    const char *left  = *( const char ** )a;
    const char *right = *( const char ** )b;

    return strcmp( left, right );
}

int main( void )
{
    char *words[] =
    {
        "The",  "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( words ) / sizeof( *words );

    char **allwords = words;

    qsort( allwords, N, sizeof( *allwords ), cmp );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts( allwords[i] );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The
brown
dog
fox
jumps
lazy
over
quick
the
```

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thanks. I made a typo when was copying the original code.:)

Comment: what do you mean by reverse casting from const void * to char **

Comment: qsort(wordle->allwords, wordle->leng, sizeof(*wordle->allwords), intcmp);

here is my qsort im working with

Comment: @DakotaKellogg The comparison function needs to know the actual type of the passed pointers to array elements.

Comment: @DakotaKellogg I guess that the type of the expression wordle->allwords is char **.

Comment: it is char **allwords

Comment: yes, but im trying to take out the words that are duplicates so that "the" would only print once.

Comment: @DakotaKellogg After sorting it will be easy to remove duplicate elements. The function qsort does not do such a task as removing elements from an array.

Comment: i see what youre saying

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use std::string and vector instead of raw pointer array.
You can write it more simply and safely.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v{ "ghi", "def", "abc", "def" };
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
    for (auto s : v) {
        printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
    }
}
```

output is sorted and unique simply

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: If the OP were programming in C++ rather than C, this would be ideal advice. They're not, however.